# Rails cannot retrieve data saved in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, I want to save the data in DB and display the saved contents on the page, but I get an error like the image below.
I was worried for 3 days, but I couldn't solve it. I would like to know the target method.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = Article.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article, notice: ""
    else
      render :new, alert: ""
    end
  end

  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article, notice: ""
    else
      render :edit, alert: ""
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @article.destroy
      redirect_to root_path, notice: ""
    else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: ""
    end
  end

  private

  def find_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # resources :tops
  # root "tops#index"

  resources :articles
  root "articles#index"

  get "/articles/index", to: "articles#index"
  get "/articles/new", to: "articles#new"
  get "/articles/show", to: "articles#show"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Kh2.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you write resources :articles it will automatically generate all the 7 routes [link](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

So, you can update your routes file like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # root "tops#index"
  resources :articles
end
```

The issue which you are facing is because you are not sending a valid ID.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `resources :articles` which will generate 7 `routes` by default. But later overriding the `show` using

```
get "/articles/index", to: "articles#index"
get "/articles/show", to: "articles#show"
```

And when `route` will be `get "/articles/index", to: "articles#index"` it assumes that the `index` is the `id` and will go to the `'articles#show'` and could not find `'id'` with `'index'` so either

`Routes` should be as

```
get '/articles', to: 'articles#index'
get '/articles/new', to: 'articles#new'
get '/articles/:id', to: 'articles#show'
post '/articles', to: 'articles#create'
delete 'articles/:id', to: 'articles#destroy'
get '/articles/:id/edit', to: 'articles#edit'
put '/articles:id', to: 'articles#update'
```

without

```
 resources :articles
  get "/articles/index", to: "articles#index"
  get "/articles/new", to: "articles#new"
  get "/articles/show", to: "articles#show"
```

in your case or you can simply use

`resources :articles` which will automatically generate all the 7 routes.

so remove these `routes`

```
get "/articles/index", to: "articles#index"
get "/articles/new", to: "articles#new"
get "/articles/show", to: "articles#show"
```